# How can we change behaviour of c++ method depending on initialization parameter?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

In python I can write something like

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, mode):
        if mode == 0:
            self.f = self.f0
        elif mode == 1:
            self.f = self.f2
        (...)
        else:
            raise KeyError

    def f0(self, a1, a2):
        <do stuff>

    def f1(self, a1, a2):
        <do other stuff>

    (...)
```

As an alternative to writing a parent class with subclasses `C1`, `C2`, ... that overwrite `f`. The short question is: Can i do something similar in C++ without summoning Cthulhu?

Before anyone asks "why":

This is useful, for example if I have another class `D`, that uses `C`, because it allows the parameter `mode` to simply be passed on to `C` rather than writing separate cases everywhere an instance of `C` is initialised.

I want to avoid a `switch` or `if`-tree that is evaluated every time `f` is called, because `f` is a small function that is called *very* many times in an already expensive calculation.

Comment: yes, look up member function pointers

Comment: branch prediction is your friend. I have some doubts that you will actually notice an `if` everytime you call `f` when the bool is constant for performance. Using a function pointer also adds a tiny overhead for the indirection

Comment: Is `mode` known at compile time?

Comment: Compiler can remove overhaed of function pointer as well (probably as long as it knows the value of `mode`): https://godbolt.org/z/59do9a5jo

Comment: Thank you for quick responses! Looking up member function pointers now, still struggling with some compile errors, but it's only been 10 min :)
@mch `mode` is not known at compile time, but it is `const`, so it cannot change after initialization. Perhaps the compiler will be able to take it from there?

Comment: @VegardJervell Check the godbolt link for a a working example ;) `std::invoke` could be replaced by the commented version before C++17.

Comment: Why would there be an `if`-tree every time you use `f`?  Based on your python code, the if/else only happens in the constructor

Comment: @VegardJervell I thought about something like https://godbolt.org/z/eTTe7j4en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlanBirtles and @Yksisarvinen !

The working solution I ended up with was

`stuff.h`:

```
class C{

    C(int mode);

    const int mode;
    double f(int i, int j, int k);

    using FunctionType = double(C::*)(int, int, int);
    double f0(int i, int j, int k);
    double f1(int i, int j, int k);
    FunctionType f_p;
};
```

`stuff.cpp`:

```
C::C(int mode) : mode{mode} {
    switch (mode){
    case 0:
        f_p = &C::f0;
        break;
    case 1:
        f_p = &C::f1;
        break;
    default: throw "Non-valid mode!";
    }
}
double C::f(int i, int j, int k) {std::invoke(f_p, this, i, j, k);}
double C::f0(int i, int j, int k){ <do stuff> }
double C::f1(int i, int j, int k){ <do other stuff>}
```

As suggested by @mch, using a template class would probably have been just as simple. However (not specified in the question) I needed this to work with a python-wrapper using `pybind11`, so the above solution allowed me to avoid any trouble related to wrapping a template class.

Comment: You'll get better results if `f0` and `f1` are static functions with an extra `C& self` input, in case they somehow use the state of `C`.